# How to change Parameter format from DD/MM/YYY HH:MM;SS to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a parameter `uploadedDate` (Data type-Date/time)
(Drop down Parameter where i can select a particular date of that records) which gets available values from query.

My issue here is while i executing that query in sql its shows only date.

But when i use that in parameter(UploadedDate) it giving date with time.

How to remove time and select only date from drop down list(Parameter)?

Comment: Can you post a comment or edit explaining what the solution was? From the comments on the accepted answer, it is unclear how you solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use convert

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),UploadedDate,103)
FROM table
```

Comment: i have problem in reporting parameter, while executing in sql server i am getting only date. but when i assign this value to parameter date/type it is showing time along with date during drop down

Comment: what is the data type assigned to the drop down?

Comment: Then its not your code it is the data type assigned to the drop down, change it to date

Comment: I made it to date ,but while giving values to parameter(Uploadeddate) which is (Type:Date/Time), by default taking some 12:00:00am for every date

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely not in the data type of the parameter, the problem is likely in the available values you are supplying for the parameter. If you clear those out, it will have a calendar type selection box with just the date by default. If you need the available values, you'll have to run a FormatDateTime function on them in expressions or, if they are brought in by query, run a convert function in the SQL, like what Matt has posted.

If you're still having issues, you can switch to a string data type parameter instead; there is no issue with using the string parameter to filter on a column whose data type is a date/time in sql.